# AdMob interstitial crashes with NullReferenceException in GoogleAds.DLL

Tags: windows-phone-8, admob, windows-phone-8.1, monogame

I am trying to integrate an interstitial AdMob ad into a Windows Phone 8 MonoGame. It is the newest version of MonoGame (3.2) and the newest version of the AdMob SDK for Windows Phone 8 (6.5.13). Ideally I would like to be able to preload the ad and show it when the player dies.

This first example works, but it calls ShowAd directly in the event handler when the ad was received.

```
public void LoadAndShowAd()
{
  interstitial = new InterstitialAd("xxx");
  interstitial.ReceivedAd += OnAdReceived;
  AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
  adRequest.ForceTesting = true;
  interstitial.LoadAd(adRequest);
}       
private void OnAdReceived(object sender, AdEventArgs e)
{
  interstitial.ShowAd();
}
```

This slightly modified example does not work. The ad is received and is ready, but the call to ShowAd crashes within the GoogleAds.DLL with a NullReferenceException. As you can see the only difference is that ShowLoadedAd is called at a later point in time when the ad is ready.

```
public void LoadAd()
{
  interstitial = new InterstitialAd("xxx");
  interstitial.ReceivedAd += OnAdReceived;
  AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
  adRequest.ForceTesting = true;
  interstitial.LoadAd(adRequest);
}       
public void ShowLoadedAd()
{
   if (isReady)
     interstitial.ShowAd();
}
private void OnAdReceived(object sender, AdEventArgs e)
{
  isReady = true;
}
```

The "interstitial" object itself is not null, the exception happens within the GoogleAds dll as shown in the stack trace below. The exception itself sadly does not give away much:

```
  System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=GoogleAds
  StackTrace:
       at A.c81d6e02e9732689b8a214cc526c72649.c8b6f578dd247fa29b178e585ca8da582()
       at A.c81d6e02e9732689b8a214cc526c72649.ce00282f6ceb6d2b777527815c84e2081()
       at GoogleAds.InterstitialAd.ShowAd()
       at GameName10.GamePage.<Test2>b__1()
  InnerException:
```

The Google Ads example for Windows Phone 8 and interstitial ads actually uses the second approach which causes the exception in my monogame project. So I assumed it could be an issue with these calls being made from the game loop of monogame being in a different thread. I wrapped all the calls to these functions in Dispatcher.BeginInvoke calls to make sure they are called on the UI thread. However this does not change anything, the first example works regardless if it is wrapped in BeginInvoke or not and the second one does not.

Any input in how to solve this issue or integrate an interstitial AdMob ad into MonoGame successfully is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: After several days of modifying the same program I discovered that a sequence of "LoadAd", successful receipt of the ad, "LoadAd", and then "ShowLoadedAd" caused the issue. The second call to "LoadAd" should not have happened and caused the error.